Visual Studio profiler for C++ for a model driven profject using ecore and uml metamodels
I have been working on something similar like this. I am working on a project which follows model driven approach in c++ using ecore, uml metamodel. I was looking for a way to profile c++ codes for possible optimizations. Th project uses cmake and gradle for build process. I wanted to use visual studio profiler as it supports cmake configuration. I created a user-defined CMakefiles.txt in the root folder so that it can traverse through all subdirectories.
but its not working. The cmake configuartion works but while building solution or such, I dont know what to do. It builds a solution like MDE4CPP.sln in the project root. But then when I configure and start performance profiler on .exe files, it doesnt show any data. Any suggestions?
# Set the minimum required version of CMake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# Set the project name
project(MDE4CPP)

# Set the C++ standard
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

# Recursively find all CMakeLists.txt files in subdirectories
# This will search in src and userProjects folders
file(GLOB_RECURSE all_subdirectories 
    RELATIVE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} 
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/* 
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/userProjects/*
)

# Loop through the found subdirectories and add them as subdirectories
foreach(subdir ${all_subdirectories})
    # Create an absolute path to the subdirectory
    set(abs_subdir "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${subdir}")
    
    # Check if a CMakeLists.txt file exists in the subdirectory
    if(EXISTS ${abs_subdir}/CMakeLists.txt)
        message(STATUS "Adding subdirectory: ${abs_subdir}")
        add_subdirectory(${abs_subdir})
    endif()
endforeach()


I have almost never found the MSVC profiler at all useful. The instrumentation it uses invariably destroys  anything important that you might want to measure. Use Intel ICX and their sampling profiler VTune if you want to see where the bottlenecks really are.

@MartinBrown Thank you for your reply. The thing is, in order to use VTune, I have to integrate with visual studio right? Now, in my main project, I have the generator directory which contains all necessary .mtl file for ecore, uml or fuml generator; basically generates the source codes and cmake files for each directory. In this case, I have to somehow recognize the build process and generator behaviour with each of the sub-project to build them in visual studio right? before utilizing Vtune?

Intel's ICX can be used outside of the MSVC environment. They just provide a way to integrate it as well. You can probably use it in your existing configuration but I have always used it integrated into MS the IDE. I suspect the learning curve is steeper for command line and alternative environments but the Intel compiler is very capable and their VTune profiler is extremely good. I'd say well worth the effort if you really need to see into difficult bottleneck code. It might be as simple as invoking the Intel ICX compiler with the right profiling options. Worth a look at their site.
